# Eclipse shortcut should only work on selected File or Project in Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings, plugin.xml

I want to add some shortcuts to my product which should only be activated if I select a DSL file or a project. There are no contextIDs which I can use so I want to define my own context. The question is if it is possible to define a context which only gets activated when a DSL file or project is selected. Because I use DSL files and Java files in the same project I created a formatter for the DSL files but I want the same shortcut for both formatters. There for I need a contextID which depends on the file type.

let me know if you need further information.

I hope you guys can help me and I hope there is a solution.

Comment: No, you can't have a context when a file is selected. The existing Format shortcut only works when an editor is open.

Comment: Thank you for this information